# SQL: How to do calculations for certain ranges of dates with all data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, range

I know title sounds simple.  However, this is really the only way I can think of wording it at the time.  Let me explain further

I get repair data on `Repairs` that I `INNER JOIN` to a `Hours` table on `SN`

I need to do calculations for every row in the table that are within a year from the start of every quarter.  The following are my org's quarter start dates:

Q1 start date = Jan 1;
Q2 start date = Apr 1;
Q3 start date = July 1;
Q4 start date = Oct 1

So, I need to count the `Failures` from `Repairs` and `#OfHours` from `Hours` - from Jan 1 to Dec. 31; Apr 1 to March 31 of following year, etc....I need to `sum` all of the failures to hours to calculate Mean Time Between Failure.

May someone help me get started on this query; it is starting to frustrate me, I'm an intern and would like to complete this without asking my manager.  Thanks

I know what I want to do but am jumbling up the syntax in my head to do it.

EDIT:

The following is my query to get the original data that I want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Hours H
INNER JOIN Repair R
ON H.SN = R.SN  
WHERE R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'OC%' OR R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'YC%'
```

Because there over 70,000 rows I will limit the result to do the calcs on to 20; sample results are the following (I only included the relevant columns:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SN    |Type    |Hours    |ReportDate    |Part    |DateReceived    | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1111  |Ford    |170      |2012-05-01    |9000000 |2012-10-19 
2222  |Ford    |170      |2012-05-01    |9000001 |2012-10-12 
3333  |Ford    |170      |2012-05-01    |9000002 |2012-10-19 
4444  |Chevy   |180      |2013-04-01    |9000001 |2014-04-04 
5555  |Chevy   |180      |2013-04-01    |9000002 |2014-03-30 
6666  |Chevy   |180      |2013-04-01    |9000003 |2014-04-04 
7777  |Dodge   |180      |2012-03-01    |9000001 |2012-03-30 
8888  |Dodge   |174      |2012-03-01    |9000001 |2012-04-04 
9999  |Dodge   |174      |2012-03-01    |9000001 |2012-03-30 
1212  |Chevy   |210      |2012-03-01    |9000002 |2012-04-04 
2323  |Lincoln |140      |2010-04-01    |9000001 |2012-05-30 
3434  |Lincoln |140      |2010-04-01    |9000002 |2012-04-04 
4545  |Lincoln |140      |2010-04-01    |9000000 |2012-03-30 
5656  |Dodge   |10       |2010-02-01    |9000004 |2012-04-04 
6767  |Chevy   |190      |2011-02-01    |9000005 |2012-03-30 
7878  |Lincoln |160      |2011-02-01    |9000000 |2012-04-04 
8989  |Dodge   |140      |2011-06-01    |9000001 |2012-03-30 
0101  |Chevy   |169      |2011-07-01    |9000001 |2012-04-04
```

I have to do MTBF Calculations `GROUPED BY` `TYPE` and `GROUPED BY` `PART`.  I need to retrieve all the report dates between the year between quarters as expressed previously.  Im jumbling this in my head and can't grasp the query to do this.

Any help would be great.  Thanks

EDIT: FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING OF WHAT I WANT TO DO

The following is a good example of what I want to do but it needs to be done for every single quarter (this query does not yield what I want though):

```
DECLARE @BeginDate date = '1013-01-01'
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM Hours H
INNER JOIN Repair R
ON H.SN = R.SN 
WHERE (R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'OC%' OR R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'YC%') AND (DATEDIFF([DAY], @BeginDate, DateReceived) <= 365) AND (DATEDIFF([DAY], @BeginDate, ReportDate) <= 365)
END
```

I want the above query to get me ALL records in which both `ReportDate` and `DateReceived` are within the year.  This would generate a yearly report PER quarter I.E.  Jan 1 - Dec 31, Apr 1 - Mar 31, Jul 1 - Sept 31, and Oct 1 - Dec 31.

Again, this is not yielding the results I want but maybe will give a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.  Again, this will have do be done for every quarter.

EDIT:  Below is what some sample output should look like given the above query. I change the `Type` column to single letters for efficiency; its not relevant:

[image]

Comment: Could you give an concrete example of your data? Like some rows with the relevant columns? Or at least the column names? That would help to help you.

Comment: Yeah...it'll be a min though...I have to "dummy" it up (sensitive)

Comment: @magic_al I provided some sample data, I also forgot to add a column `Date Received` from `Repairs` which is the date of failure...the `ReportDate` column is the monthly report date I get regarding how many hours in operation.

Comment: @magic_al I also added the "dummy" `DateReceived` data

Comment: (1) For the data provided, can you give an example of what you want for output; (2) `R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'OC' OR R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'YC'` doesn't do what you expect.  It selects all non-NULL `R.Confirmed` values.  Use `AND` instead.

Comment: @magic_al My fault...it should be `NOT LIKE 'OC%' OR NOT LIKE 'YC%'`  These are confirmed codes that end with a bunch of jibberish.  There are like 5 other confirmed codes that the calcs need to be done on

Comment: @magic_al I'm even having a hard time writing down pseudo code lol...I think the pseudo code would be something like, "for each record grab each report date that is between end of last quarter and beginning of quarter a year before that and grab how many hours it ran and how many times it failed to calculate mean time between failure."  I hope that helps a little.  I have 6 good months of SQL but this is the toughest query I've had to write.  Also, is this something that can easily be done in SSIS, this is part of an aggregate SSIS package.

Comment: @JeffOrris - please show us the sample output, with any comments if necessary. Its easier to understand your problem instead of reading all the english.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I have added the sample output in the question from the `JOIN` query...Im adding another T-SQL query to give an example of what I'm trying to do....although the output is wrong.  It will be just an example as this need to be done at the start of every quarter

Comment: @JeffOrris - Actually, I was expecting an output table and not a query. From a quick glance at your question it seems that you only want to do some quarterly processing on the table which you gave. This table is obtained from your join query. Is that correct ? Can you put the expected output in an excel sheet and copy paste it here ? Eg. If you were expecting a grouping by Type and summing by hours for type, you would show us an output table with Type and hour column only. Then, we'd be able to tell you that you need `GROUP BY` to get the output. Makes sense ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev You are absolutely correct in what you have deduced.  Give me a min and I will whip up some sample output that I want.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I added what some sample output should look like given the T-SQL query I added...notice that the date columns in the sample output are within the range provided by my `@BeginDate` in the T-Sql query

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not everything you wanted (you mentioned MTBF), but should be enough to get you close enough. Based on the data you showed, here is a report of each part, how many times it failed and the number of repair hours for each year preceding each listed quarter. Note that your insistence that ReportDate *and* DateReceived be in the same trailing year will lead to misleading results as it will not include, for example, SN 4545 with ReportDate 1/4/2010 and ReceivedDate 3/30/2012. That's 140 hours that will not show up anywhere in the report. Is that really what you want?

```
WITH
Quarters AS
( SELECT  DATE '2011-01-01' as Quarter FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2011-04-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2011-07-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2011-10-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2012-01-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2012-04-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2012-07-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2012-10-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2013-01-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2013-04-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2013-07-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATE '2013-10-01' FROM dual
),
ByQuarter AS
( SELECT  h.*, R.PART, R.DATERXD, Q.Quarter
  FROM    Hours H
  JOIN    REPAIR R
    ON    H.SN = R.SN
  JOIN    Quarters q
    ON    q.Quarter - r.DateRxd BETWEEN 1 AND 365
      AND q.Quarter - h.RptDate BETWEEN 1 AND 365
)
-- select  * from ByQuarter ORDER BY Quarter, RptDate, sn; -- Examine "raw" data
  SELECT  bq.Part, bq.Quarter, Count(1) as Failures, Sum( bq.Hours ) AS TotalHours
  FROM    ByQuarter bq
  GROUP BY Part, Quarter
  order by Part, Quarter;
```